# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build - Flutter android app build fail

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Flutter app builds fine on iOS but fails to build Android App:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/dhwanitzaveri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/irondash_engine_context-0.4.0/cargokit/gradle/plugin.gradle' line: 59

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':irondash_engine_context:cargokitCargoBuildIrondash_engine_context_nativeDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/dhwanitzaveri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/irondash_engine_context-0.4.0/cargokit/gradle/../run_build_tool.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/dhwanitzaveri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/super_native_extensions-0.7.3/cargokit/gradle/plugin.gradle' line: 59

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':super_native_extensions:cargokitCargoBuildSuper_native_extensionsDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/dhwanitzaveri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/super_native_extensions-0.7.3/cargokit/gradle/../run_build_tool.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 41s
351 actionable tasks: 346 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

Not sure what the issue is - i've tried `flutter clean`, deleting the android folder and `flutter create . --platforms=android`, upgrading and downgrading gradle but none of it has worked.

The packages referred to are standard flutter packages so i can't even change them?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .pub-cache folder ?

Comment: I hadnt previously - just did but unfortunately didnt change anything

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and my problem was missing the 'keystore' jks file.

Comment: i solved it with adding the keystore as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add the release keystore/jks and properties file in the android folder.

Answer (score 0):

This will sound crazy - but my issue got fixed once I added flutter to my PATH...